# How to stay below Photon's 500 msg/sec limit while using DF Voice

Tags: voip, multiplayer, photon

I'm developing a game similar to Second Life on Unity3D v5.3.3 Engine. Its multiplayer (obviously).
Using Photon as my multiplayer solution. The game is VoIP capable. Using DF Voice for VoIP. 
A room can contain upto 50 members. However, only 1-2 members can speak. This voice data has to reach all the 50 members in the room. Unfortunately, Photon has a limit of 500 msg/sec. Using only text to chat is fine and stays below the 500 limit. However, the problem arises when using voice to chat.
The limit is crossed easily with voice data. Is there any way i can limit the voice data being transmitted so that it stays below the 500 limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) PUN is designed to support 2 .. 16 players per room.
There are some tricks - but in general it is limited to the broadcast concept.

See http://www.m2h.nl/network-traffic-culling/ or http://blog.exitgames.com/2014/12/radial-g-devstory.

2) Messages are creating bandwidth - this is the major cost driver.
You need to split gameplay and voice data.
https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Voice provides the latter.